# PDF Structure using tcpdf

Tags: php, html, css, pdf, tcpdf

I am creating PDF file with custom structure/layout using TCPDF library. Data is coming from server side and data is being displayed data in tabular form in PDF file.

PDF structure should be look like this
[Required PDF structure](http://websiteexcellent.com/SAMPLE.pdf)

Based on my code. PDF structure/[PDF structure based on my code](http://websiteexcellent.com/Members(91).PDF)

Actually, I this this layout in PDF file

Sheet Size : 210x297 mm (A4) 
Format 6 (Row) x 3 (Col)
Label Size : 63.5 x 46.6
Margins :  Left  7 mm,  Right  8 mm, Gutter 2 mm
Top  10.4 mm   Bottom 7 mm

I am using sheet size like this

```
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, array('210', '297'), true, 'UTF-8', false);
```

I am using Label (First column) size like this. I don't know it's correct or not but it looks like correct.

```
$subhtml .= '<td border="0" width="63.5mm" height="46.6mm style="float:left;text-align:left;">
```

I am using Margins (Left, Right,Top) like this and I don't know how to give gutter (space between two columns)

```
$pdf->SetMargins(7, 10.4, 8);
```

Bottom 7 MM like this

```
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(7);
```

**PROBLEMS**

1. Left side space is not same as in required PDF structure file.
2. How to give gutter/space between two columns.
3. All above code are correct or not?

**Complete Code**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Members where MemberId in (select MemberId from Normalized_Category where Category IN (".addQuotes($categories)."))";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $members[] = $rows; 
    }

    $subhtml ='';              
    $i = 1;
    $j = 3;
    $html ='';

    foreach($members as $value){
        $subhtml .= '<td border="0" width="63.5mm" height="46.6mm" style="float:left;text-align:left;">

        <span>'.$value['MemberId'].'</span>

        <span style="float:right; text-align:right;">'.$value['Expiry_Date'].'</span>
        <br/><b>
        <span>'.$value['Salute'].'&nbsp;'.$value['Name'].'</span>
        </b><br/>
        <span>'.$value['Address1'].','.$value['Address2'].','.$value['Address3'].' </span>
        <br/><span>'.$value['City'].'&nbsp;'.$value['PinCode'].' - '.$value['State'].'</span><br/>
        <span>'.$value['Contact'].'</span><br/></td>';
        if ($i % $j == 0) {
            $subhtml .= '</tr><tr>';
         }

        $i++;
    }

    $tbl = <<<EOD
    <table border="0" cellpadding="2"  align="justify">
    <tr nobr="true">
    <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr nobr="true">
    $subhtml
    </tr>
    </table>
EOD;

    require('tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
    $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, array('210', '297'), true, 'UTF-8', false);
    $pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

    $pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
    $pdf->setPrintFooter(false);

    $pdf->SetMargins(7, 10.4, 8); // left = 2.5 cm, top = 
    $pdf->SetFooterMargin(7); 

    if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php')) {
        require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php');
        $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
    }
    $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 9);
    $pdf->AddPage();

    $pdf->writeHTML($tbl, true, false, false, false, '');
    $pdf->Output('Members.PDF', 'D');
```

Comment: I recommend using mpdf https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf

Comment: @Saurabh - I think, it's also possible using TCPDF and I can't use mpdf only to fix this.

Comment: Why downvote?. Can you please explain?

Comment: your very much restricted when using the tcpdf html parsing. I personally gone away from using those and use multicells. Theoretically it's just plain simple math to place the cells on the page and when to create a new one since to me it looks like these should have pretty much the same heights and widths to begin with.